# Why does this stored procedure execute when an user does ALTER USER .... DISABLE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, wherescape-red

A specific user - `Main_user` (with a default database of `db_A`) executes

```
USE db_A
ALTER USER another_user DISABLE;
```

Every time it tries to do so, an error message is shown:

> Msg 916, Level 14, State 2, Server ****, Procedure *****sysadmin, Line 32
> The server principal Main_user is not able to access the database db_ZZZ under the current security context.

As you can see, it seems that the procedure tries to execute code that involves `db_ZZZ`, which apparently has nothing to do with the `ALTER USER` statement.

The thing is that I cannot find the procedure `******sysadmin` anywhere (not a trigger, nothing). And I can't understand what is the business of it in all this situation.

What explanations could be plausible?

I don't know if it could be useful to mention that `Main_user` is a service user of Wherescape RED. I cannot test this code with any other user because I don't have any other with permission to do so.

Comment: Seems you have a database trigger, which is then trying to execute the procedure `*****sysadmin` in the database `db_ZZZ`, and the `LOGIN` linked to the `USER` you are connected with doesn't have access to that procedure (or database more specifically).

Comment: We are not able to find the `*****sysadmin` procedure in `db_ZZZ` or anywhere.

Comment: Then you have a problem there too, it's referencing an object that has been `DROP`ed. You need to fix your database trigger.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have a DDL trigger enabled on your server. To see if that's the case, look in the `sys.server_triggers` system view or, in SSMS, look under Server Objects → Triggers. From there, you should be able to see what the trigger's definition is and make a decision as to whether you want to keep it (with modifications so that it actually works) or drop it altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Like Larnu said. You can find the trigger using this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   sys.triggers AS t
       JOIN sys.all_sql_modules AS asm ON asm.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE  asm.definition LIKE '%*****sysadmin%';
```

Comment: Because this is a DDL trigger, I don't think it will show up in `sys.triggers` (which is for database-scoped DML triggers). See [the example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-ver16#ddl-trigger-scope) on how they check for the trigger's existence.

Comment: I created a database trigger on alter user, found it with query above, however depending on where the trigger is located, your location can be better to use :)

Comment: Don't worry guys, I can't find anything with none of the two methods. This is a mistery to me. As you say, Peter, maybe the trigger (if there is one) is located somewhere else... but I looked anywehere in the server.

Comment: @Aleix - have you tried turning on query plans when you run your `alter user` command?

Comment: I just queried the cached plans. Turns out the first row of returned results is the plan for the trigger `******sysadim`! It begins as follows : `CREATE TRIGER ... ON all server FOR alter login`. Althought I couldnt find the trigger even querying `sys.server_triggers`. Maybe the user doesn't have permission even to do so? I guess that with the right permissions we can run `DROP TRIGGER...` .

Comment: Great, and.. Ben, good one!